# Vtiger Query webservice returnes 403 access forbidden error in postman

Tags: php, vtiger

I am new to vtiger and recently I tried working with third party API integration of vtiger where we can have a query webservice. I tried following API in Postman
http://myurl/webservice.php?operation=query&sessionName=63c67873606f00c2d94fa&query=select count(*) from Leads where Leadid = 1
which is giving 403 error. Also please let me know where to create a webservice in vtiger.

Answer (score 0):

You have to authenticate:

First, get a challenge token:

`GET /webservice.php?operation=getchallenge&username=<USERNAME> HTTP/1.1`

Then use that token, together with a username and the accesskey of that user (not to be confused with the user's password) to login:

```
POST /webservice.php HTTP/1.1

operation=login
username=<USERNAME>
accessKey=md5(TOKENSTRING + <ACCESSKEY>) // Note: accessKey= K here is capitalized.
```

Notice that the concatenation of TOKENSTRING and ACCESSKEY need to be encoded using the md5 function. I recommend using php to do that operation because I've had problems using online encoders.

About the second question, take a look at the folder `include/Webservices`. Many of the files under that folder are ws functions and you have to create something similar. After created, you have to register

1. the function by calling `vtws_addWebserviceOperation()`  and
2. each parameter of the function by calling `vtws_addWebserviceOperationParam`.

Both of the above functions are defined under `/include/Webservices/Utils.php`

source: https://community.vtiger.com/help/vtigercrm/developers/third-party-app-integration.html

Comment: Ofcourse I did authentication first , then using the token key I logged in inside my admin login. But the problem is when I use coditional queyr it gives me authorization issue even when I have isentity as true. And when I simply fetch data without condtion is works..

Comment: Well, why don't you add that to your question? Post the query that lets you retrieve information and the one that doesn't. That's valuable information in order to be able to better assist you.